# How to warp image around cylinder?

Tags: php, imagick, warp

I am just starting to learn PHP's Imagick library and I am needing to warp an image around a cyclinder. I have been using the following examples:

http://www.phpimagick.com/Imagick/rotateImage

To successfully rotate/scale/extent etc. the image but cannot see how I can wrap it round a cylinder.

I can see there is a way of doing so with `Cylindrical Displacement` in the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/mapping/#displace_cylinder):

```
convert rose: -background black -gravity south -splice 0x8 \
      \( +clone -sparse-color barycentric '0,0 black 69,0 white' \) \
      \( +clone -function arcsin 0.5 \) \
      \( -clone 1 -level 25%,75% \
             -function polynomial -4,4,0 -gamma 2 \
             +level 50%,0 \) \
      -delete 1 -swap 0,1  miff:- |\
 composite - -virtual-pixel black  -displace 17x7  rose_cylinder.png
```

This just doesn't make much sense to me when I've been using code such as:

```
$img = new Imagick($the_img_path);
// to resize
$img->resizeImage($_w, $_h, imagick::FILTER_LANCZOS, 1, false);
// to crop
$img->cropImage($crop_w, $crop_h, $crop_x, $crop_y);
```

Answer (score 0):

PHP Imagick provides mostly all functions from console util. You have just to find appropriate analogs from function list:

http://php.net/manual/en/book.imagick.php

So for `sparse` you have to use [Imagick::sparseColorImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.sparsecolorimage.php). To apply a function: [Imagick::functionImage](http://php.net/manual/en/imagick.functionimage.php). And so on.

You code will be similar to:

```
$original = new Imagick('rose');
$original->setBackgroundColor('black');
$original->setGravity('south')
$original->spliceImage(...);

$clone = clone $original;
$clone->functionImage(...);

...
```

Comment: So do i place `convert rose: -back....` inside functionImage() so it would be: `$img->functionImage(convert rose: -back....);`?

Comment: Nope. Every argument in example command is a operation that would be performed with a source image:

    -background black // setBackground
    -gravity south // setGravity 

Then you have operations grouped in brackets. Each group stars with clone so it operates copied source